# my protocol isn't working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, protocols

i've been trying to implement this protocol for several hours and it doesn't seem to work for some reason.  Basically i have a split view which has a view controller and a table controller, one class holds these two together.  The main class creates an instance of the table and runs perfectly, but if i select a cell i want the view controller to react.  So i wanted to create a protocol for when a table cell is selected it will do something in the main class.

TableSplitViewController, this is the main class:

```
    @interface TableSplitViewController : UIViewController <updateView>
    {
            ChildrenTableViewController *firstController;
            IBOutlet UITableView *firstTable;
        IBOutlet UITableViewCell *tablecell;
        NSString *name;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *childnamelabel;


    @end
```

THis is the TableSplitViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (firstController == nil) {
        firstController = [[ChildrenTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    }
        [firstTable setDataSource:firstController];
        [firstTable setDelegate:firstController];
        firstController.view = firstController.tableView;




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowChildrenDetails"]) {
        ChildrenDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [firstController.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        detailViewController.childrenDetailModel = [[NSArray alloc]
                                                    initWithObjects: [firstController.childname objectAtIndex:[firstController.index row]], nil];
    }
}
- (void) setNameLabel:(NSString *)sender
{
   // self.name = sender;
    NSLog(@"ran");
}
```

This is the ChildrenTableViewController.h:

```
@protocol updateView <NSObject>
@required
- (void) setNameLabel:(NSString *)sender;
@end

@interface ChildrenTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSIndexPath *index;
    id <updateView> delegate1;

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *childname;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *index;

@property (retain) id delegate1;

@end
```

This is the critical part of ChildrenTableViewController.m:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[self delegate1] setNameLabel:[self.childname objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    NSLog(@"rannn");
```

As you can see in the last code i'm trying to call the method using the protocol function.  It doesn't seem to work for some reason, i've put in NSLOG and it doesn't even run the setNameLabel method at all. :( Will appreciate any help offered :)

Comment: where have you set the the `delegate1`'s value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code above I cant see you setting the delegate as so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (firstController == nil) {
        firstController = [[ChildrenTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    }

    [firstTable setDataSource:firstController];
    [firstTable setDelegate:firstController];
    firstController.view = firstController.tableView;

    // Set up the delegate for the controller
    [firstController setDelegate1:self];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Also, the delegate property should usually be (weak) rather than (retain).